# Which verse in the Agni Purāṇa forbids the enslavement of prisoners?

Tags: puranas, agni-purana

In [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_and_religion#Hinduism) on "slavery and religion", it is stated that the Agni Purāṇa forbids the enslavement of prisoners:

> The Agni Purana forbids enslavement of prisoners.

Which particular Agni Purāṇa verse is Wikipedia refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only verse, although remotely close, I could find mentions the following:

> Fire-god said:
>
> ...
>
> One who has saved the life of his master and has been forcibly made a slave by thieves and sold should be made free (by the king) even by paying a ransom.
>
> From: [Agnipurāṇa verse 257.33](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083486.html)

The Sanskrit verse runs as follows:

> balāddāsīkṛtaścaurairvikrītaścāpi mucyate |
> svāmiprāṇapado bhaktatyāgāttanniṣkrayādapi ||
>
> [Source](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%AB%E0%A5%AD)

Comment: While slavery is allowed, the rules against harming/killing/insulting the members of the Chaturvarna make no distinction for slaves, so must still apply. Also, Hinduism has cultures of radically different technologies living together, so being a slave in a high technology world is probably more comfortable than outside it.

Comment: Also, I think the absence of a punishment for harming/killing/insulting someone outside the Chaturvarna is because of things that are technically human, but no one cares if killed e.g. human cancer. For example, if you are okay with having children you are okay with the murder of all the failed fertilised eggs and embryoes, which are greater than the number of humans you think the "rule" applies to.

Comment: In order to give an sensible rule in place of "do not murder" the scriptures would have to go into so much detail it would be blindingly obvious they know what they are talking about, which they seem reluctant to do for some reason. Probably because atheism makes more sense than what most religious people believe.